# convert array with dict to variables

Tags: python

I have an array with dict

```
 tag_list = [{'Key': 'backup', 'Value': 'true'},
 {'Key': 'backup_daily', 'Value': '7'}]
```

I'd like to convert it to variables, such as:

```
tag_backup = 'true'
tag_backup_daily = '7'
```

Any easy way to do that?

If no need to convert it to variables, any other better way to reference these key/value directly?

The best I want to do is to reference as below ways.

```
tag_list['backup'] = "true"
tag_list['backup_daily'] = "7"
```

#### UPDATE #1

Thanks to @Lev Zakharov 's answer, I did with below ways.

```
>>> new_list = {x['Key']: x['Value'] for x in tag_list}
>>> new_list['backup']
'true'
>>> new_list['backup_daily']
'7'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use simple dict comprehension:

```
{x['Key']:x['Value'] for x in tag_list}
```

Result:

```
{'backup': 'true', 'backup_daily': '7'}
```

Comment: I got your point now. You ask to generate a new dict with key/value directly. `new_list = {x['Key']:x['Value'] for x in tag_list['TagList']}`

Answer (score 6):

You could use `globals()`:

```
tag_list = [{'Key': 'backup', 'Value': 'true'},
 {'Key': 'backup_daily', 'Value': '7'}]

for x in tag_list:
    globals()[f"tag_{x['Key']}"] = x['Value']

print(tag_backup)  # true
print(tag_backup_daily)  # 7
```

Comment: What's `f`? Where did you define it?

Comment: "How to make your code more incomprehensible":) But really interesting solution!

Comment: @FrankAK: `f` stands for `f`-strings - The newest way of formatting strings in Python.

Comment: @Austin It's from `python 3.x?

Comment: @FrankAK, it's from Python 3.6

Comment: @Austin Cool! Good to know it. Thank you.

Comment: @FrankAK, if you using a Python version < 3.6 you can use `globals()['tag_{Key}'.format(**t)] = t['Value']`

Answer (score 3):

You just use a `for` loop

```
In [184]: def to_dict(tags):
     ...:     d = {}
     ...:     for t in tags:
     ...:         d[t['Key']] = t['Value']
     ...:     return d
     ...:

In [185]: to_dict(tag_list)
Out[185]: {'backup': 'true', 'backup_daily': '7'}
```

You *could* also use `map` and `lambda` to create a container of `tuple`s and then convert to a `dict` with its constructor

```
In [178]: dict(map(lambda d: (d['Key'], d['Value']), tag_list))
Out[178]: {'backup': 'true', 'backup_daily': '7'}
```

Note, that this is a lot slower due to the `dict` constructor

```
In [207]: %timeit to_dict(tag_list)
The slowest run took 31.74 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 431 ns per loop

In [181]: %timeit {d['Key']: d['Value'] for d in tag_list}
The slowest run took 44.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 457 ns per loop

In [182]: %timeit dict(map(lambda d: (d['Key'], d['Value']), tag_list))
The slowest run took 7.72 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.21 µs per loop
```

Comment: I think to use this as solution, because I run the codes in `aws lambda`. Less time is better, this is an extra reward I got.

Comment: @Bill But `for` loop solution slower than solution with dict comprehension.

Comment: I use the lambda one, see my updates in my question. No need `for loop`

Comment: @Bill yeah, but solution with lambda also slower:) Dict comprehension takes 457 **nanoseconds** vs 1.21 **microseconds**!

Comment: And if you use `was lambda` it bears no relation to python lambdas:)

Comment: @Bill, the `lambda` is the *slowest* of all of the methods shown!

Comment: the best answers are the `for` loop or the `dict` comprehension